# Reversing slider plugin for a volume control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been modifiying this plugin: http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/ so that it works vertically instead of horizontally for a volume control.

I've also managed to get it to position the fill and handle in the correct reverse order. So for example if I set the value to 75 it has it towards the top rather than the bottom.

But I'm struggling to get it to do it when clicking and dragging. Currently if I click the top of the slider it will put the value at 0 and if I drag down the handle will move up. So it needs to do these in reverse.

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/g7yhLkt1/

It seems that the problem is located in these two areas:

```
Plugin.prototype.handleDown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$document.on(this.moveEvent, this.handleMove);
    this.$document.on(this.endEvent, this.handleEnd);

    // If we click on the handle don't set the new position
    if ((' ' + e.target.className + ' ').replace(/[\n\t]/g, ' ').indexOf(this.options.handleClass) > -1) {
        return;
    }

    var posY    = this.getRelativePosition(e),
        rangeY  = this.$range[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
        handleY = this.getPositionFromNode(this.$handle[0]) - rangeY;

    this.setPosition(posY - this.grabY);

    if (posY >= handleY && posY < handleY + this.handleHeight) {
        this.grabY = posY - handleY;
    }
};

Plugin.prototype.handleMove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var posY = this.getRelativePosition(e);
    this.setPosition(posY - this.grabY);
};
```

Both use the `setPosition` function (which seems to fine, as if I manually set the value then it's in the correct position). So it would seem they pass incorrect values for the click and drag. And they also both use the `getRelativePosition` function to get the position relative to the slider.

The `getRelativePosition` function looks like:

```
Plugin.prototype.getRelativePosition = function(e) {
    // Get the offset left relative to the viewport
    var rangeY  = this.$range[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
        pageY   = 0;

    if (typeof e.pageY !== 'undefined') {
        pageY = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (typeof e.originalEvent.clientY !== 'undefined') {
        pageY = e.originalEvent.clientY;
    }
    else if (e.originalEvent.touches && e.originalEvent.touches[0] && typeof e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY !== 'undefined') {
        pageY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
    }
    else if(e.currentPoint && typeof e.currentPoint.y !== 'undefined') {
        pageY = e.currentPoint.y;
    }
    return pageY - rangeY;
};
```

I've not quite sure which function has the issue for me to amend. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change 2 lines of your code.

In the *'Plugin.prototype.handleDown'* method, you need to change the `this.setPosition(posY - this.grabY);` line to `this.setPosition(this.maxHandleY - (posY - this.grabY));`

And in the *'Plugin.prototype.handleMove'* method you need to change the `this.setPosition(posY - this.grabY);` line to `this.setPosition(this.maxHandleY - (posY - this.grabY));`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g7yhLkt1/5/